# Python Wordcloud only shows variable name

Tags: python, word-cloud

I'm using spyder to make a wordcloud from customers comments about a company, I have a data frame with all the information, the problem I have is that when I show the Word Cloud I only get the variable name, "Comment"

About Comments variable: there are some nan, I have multiple words in one register since it is a comment

[image: Word Cloud]

Maybe I have a simple error in the script but I don't know what is wrong.

```
base=pd.read_csv(r"C:\xxx.csv",encoding = "latin",sep=';')
base.Comment=base.Comment.astype(str)
base['Comment'] = base['Comment'].apply(lambda x: re.sub('[¡!@#$:).;,¿?&]', '', x.lower()))
base['Comment']  = base['Comment'].apply(lambda x: re.sub('  ', ' ', x))

wordcloud= WordCloud(background_color='salmon', stopwords=stop_words_sp).generate('Attention')
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.axis('off')
plt.title("NPS Word Cloud")
plt.imshow(wordcloud)
plt.show()
```

I appreciate any help,

Comment: The `generate()` method should be given the text to be turned into a cloud - your code seems to give it `’Attention’`.

Comment: follow my successful wordcloud project code which is part of **Google IT Automation with Python Professional Certificate** https://www.github.com/IT-Support-L2/WordCloud/tree/master/word_cloud.py

Comment: you need word frequencies dict, so actually you are only generating the word "comment" coz there is no word frequency dict, wordcloud is generated on the basis of **word frequencies dictionary**